# How can i listen to insert_at for Polygon that has been created by code in Google Maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map which i use the drawingManager to draw on the map and register listeners to catch the insert_at, set_at and remove_at and all works fine.

```
google.maps.event.addListener( this.drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (event) => {
        if (event.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
          const paths = event.overlay.getPaths();
          for (let p = 0; p < paths.getLength(); p++) {

     google.maps.event.addListener(paths.getAt(p), 'insert_at', () => {
                console.log('We inserted a point');
                self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
              }
            );
```

But i also load Polygon's from my DB the user has saved before and register listeners. The problem is that the insert_at for example does not work. The dragstart and dragend work fine. So how would one register a listener for insert_at on a Polygon that was created via code and not with drawingManager.

```
loadPolygon() {
    const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      draggable: true,
      editable: true,
      paths: this.polygonPts,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'dragstart', () => {
      console.log('Polygon started drag');
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'insert_at', () => {
      console.log('We inserted a point');
    }
  );
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'dragend', () => {
    console.log('Polygon moved finished drag');  
  });
    polygon.setMap(this.map);
  }
```

Comment: The same way you did it for the drawing manager. Polygon doesn't have an `insert_at` event. MVCArray does. Get the polygon path(s) and register the event on the path(s).

Answer (score -1):

After some playing arround i found the answer how to get these event listeners to work when generated by code.

```
 const paths = polygon.getPaths();
    for (let p = 0; p < paths.getLength(); p++) {

      google.maps.event.addListener(paths.getAt(p), 'insert_at', () => {
        console.log('We inserted a point');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(paths.getAt(p), 'remove_at', () => {
        console.log('We removed a point');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(paths.getAt(p), 'set_at', () => {
        console.log('We set a point');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Even so i figured it out I am wondering if there is a benefit of using the drawingManager with overlaycomplete to register the events when i draw a new item or is it the same if I use the polygoncomplete ? Both work...